# Error datepicker en laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, datepicker, jquery-datepicker

estoy trabajando con datepicker de bootstrap en mi aplicación desarrollada en laravel 5.6.  Funciona bien, hasta que le agrego la opción de setStarDate y setEndDate cuando comienza a lanzar el error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

Las librerias de datepicker están agregadas en el template master en la sección

```
@yield('adminlte_css')
<!-- datepicker -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Intenté añadirlas en otra sección (js) pero no me funciona.

El asunto es qué estoy haciendo mal, que no me funciona cuando quiero emplear esas opciones de set para las fechas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código script del calendario está antes de cerrar 
         @section('content')

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#datedesde').datepicker({  
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    language: 'es',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true, 
   }).on('changeDate',
function (selected) {
    $('#datehasta').datepicker('setStartDate', $('#datedesde').val());

});

$('#datehasta').datepicker({  
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    language: 'es',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,

}).on('changeDate',
function (selected) {
    $('#datedesde').datepicker('setEndDate', $('#datehasta').val());

});
</script>

 @stop
```

Comment: Hola @Virginia. Cual es tu codigo js? Donde estas intentando hacerlo?

Comment: @FranIslas edité la pregunta para incluir el código js

Answer (score 0):

Cambia:

```
$('#datehasta').datepicker('setStarDate', $('#datedesde').val());
```

por:

```
$('#datehasta').datepicker('setStartDate', $('#datedesde').val());
```

La diferencia es que es 'setStartDate' no 'setStarDate'...

Comment: Si, tenía un error de tipeo, ya tantas veces que lo habia escrito y borrado, pero no, el error sigue igual.  @jmarrdiaz

Answer (score 0):

Puede hacerlo capturando el evento `"change"` de los input y luego enviando las opciones `"minDate"` y `"maxDate"`.  Si deseas que que haya una diferencia minima de 1 dia entre "desde" y "hasta", puedes sumarle un dia simplemente sumando 1 a la variable `"minDate"` antes de asignarla. Cualquier duda puedes consultar. Saludos!

El código te quedaría algo así:

```js
$(function() {
      var defaults = {
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '<Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig>',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: '',
        autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    };

    $.datepicker.setDefaults(defaults);
  
      $('#datepickerDesde').datepicker()
    .on('change', function(e) {
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
              if (minDate) { 
                   $('#datepickerHasta').datepicker('setDate', minDate).
              datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
              }
             
        
    });
  
   $('#datepickerHasta').datepicker()
    .on('change', function(e) {
        var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
              if (maxDate) { 
                   $('#datepickerDesde').datepicker('setDate', maxDate).
              datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);
              }
             
        
    });


  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div  class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
   <label for="datepickerDesde">Desde:</label>
    <input id="datepickerDesde" readonly  type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div  class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
   <label for="datepickerHasta">Hasta:</label>
    <input id="datepickerHasta" readonly type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por su colaboración, probé con las soluciones propuestas y seguía con el mismo problema, hasta que revisé detenidamente como se forma el html desde laravel y encontré que lo mejor esa llevar la librería de datepicker al template page, incluyendo todo lo que necesito en el @section('adminlte_js').

Lo dejo por acá por si alguien lo necesita.